# How can I format a float number so that it looks like real time?

Tags: c#, xna

**Update! I measure the time like this:
float delta = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
time += delta;**

I want to format a float number so that it looks like this:

```
minutes:seconds.milliseconds
"0:36.763"
```

[image: Mario Kart picture]

How can I do that?

Comment: What value does the float represent?

Comment: What ever the float represents - minutes, seconds, milliseconds or ticks - there's a `DateTime` constructor or method that will convert that value to into a `DateTime`. You can then use the `ToString()` method with the appropriate formatting to get the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is *vague* one, providing that `float` contains *seconds*, e.g.

```
 float time = 156.763122f; // 2 minutes (120 seconds) and 36.763122 seconds
```

You can put (*C# 6.0*)

```
 string result = $"{(int)time / 60}:{time%60:00.000}";
```

Or

```
 string result = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
   "{0}:{1:00.000}", (int)time / 60, time % 60);
```

A better approach, however, is to use `TimeSpan` which has been designed for that purpose:

```
 TimeSpan ts = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);

 String result = ts.ToString("m\\:ss\\.fff")
```

Comment: @MickyD: I see, `f3` format string is not the best option; but `00.000` will do

Answer (score 1):

You are using a time span, so you can use a `TimeSpan` object and make use of its custom formatting:

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(36.763);
Console.WriteLine(timeSpan.ToString("m\\:ss\\.fff"));
```

This outputs: `0:36.763`

The `m` specifier denotes single digit minutes, `ss` denotes double digit secnds and `.fff` denotes three decimal places of milliseconds.

The `\\:` is an escape sequence for `:` and `\\.` is an escape sequence for `.`.

You could also write the custom format string as `@"m\:ss\.fff"`

You can also specify days, hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds separately if you happen to have the interval represented that way:

```
var timeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 36, 763); // (days, hours, mins, secs, ms)
```

Comment: That's the best way - using class that's specially designed for the purpose; propably, `TimeSpan.FromSeconds` should be used instead of `new TimeSpan(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question is referring to *TimeSpan formatting*. If these answers aren't sufficient, you'll find plenty of information using that keyword. **I've typically used the following approach.**

```
 float time = 75.405f;
 TimeSpan TimeInSeconds = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time);
 string StringTime = TimeInSeconds.ToString(@"m\:ss\.fff");

 Console.WriteLine(StringTime);
```

The output of which is

```
1:15.405
```

You'll likely want to store your game timer in *float seconds*. You can convert that to a TimeSpan by specifying from which format you're using (seconds). After that, you can simply convert using the TimeSpan's `ToString()` method with the correct format specifiers. More information can be found here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

By the way, I noticed you've tagged your question as XNA. While XNA is fantastic by all measures, keep in mind that XNA is depreciated and you may want to consider porting to MonoGame or SFML.NET.